# How can I check a char in oracle sql from a select query?

Tags: oracle

I need to be able to check a different table's value before allowing input in separate table.
In oracle they don't allow subqueries in check so I am trying to make a function...

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION chktrain(tid integer)
    RETURN INTEGER
    AS
    chk1 char;
    BEGIN 
    SELECT chk1 = (select train from trainer where trainer.trainer_id = tid);
    IF chk1 = 'Y' THEN
    return 1;
    ELSE 
    return 0;
    END IF;
    END;
```

This won't work because I can't set chk1 to the subquery. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please tag your question either `mysql` or `oracle` not both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the [SELECT INTO statement](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/selectinto_statement.htm).

I'm not entirely sure you need to use this function you are creating though, but I'm also not sure I fully understand what you are trying to do.  Perhaps look into triggers, specifically [BEFORE INSERT triggers](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/before_insert.php), which could allow you to lookup a reference table and potentially translate a value every time you do an insert on a table.

Comment: I am looking into triggers now. When I tried check(myfunction(tid) = 1) it says I cannot reference other columns.

Comment: Not understanding how triggers are going to help me. I just need to check one value in another table and then proceed an insert if that value is 'yes' instead of 'no'.  Why wouldn't the function work if it is always going to only only get one char back

Answer (score 0):

You might find this documentation interesting and helpful.
You will find railroad diagrams for the syntax of if statements and usage details about the different forms of if statements.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/if_statement.htm

At the end of the page there is an example of the SELECT INTO statement.

(select train INTO chk1 from trainer  where trainer.trainer_id = tid);

Comment: You need to provide context for the link you shared by capturing key aspects of the article that directly answer the question - this way even if the link is removed your answer will still be helpful.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla Thank you. I will make sure to read the Help Center page on answering questions.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `SELECT INTO` statement like

```
SELECT train into chk1 from trainer 
where trainer_id = tid;
```